# How can I format my maple code so it looks presentable?

Tags: formatting, latex, maple

I have a couple of questions concerning formatting my Maplesoft code:

1) Right now all solutions are centered. I would like to view them inline. Is there any way I can put all solutions inline at once?

2) Is there a way to substitute my variables with the values, so I can first show the equation with variables, then the equation with the values, and lastly the solution?

3) I have exported my code to LaTeX, but found the output very messy. For example every line I calculated in Maple was printed twice in LaTeX. Do you know how I could solve this? Or any other tips on using LaTeX with Maple?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your try in maple?

Comment: Asking multiple questions is [generally ill-advised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). I suggest you create a new question for the third part. Also, please follow the suggestion @MapleSE-Area51Proposal to add an example.

Comment: @Therkel Is it possible to solve 2D heat equation using `pdsolve` numerically? I tried but not luck.